# What is the best way of passing data to the next handler in Giraffe routes?

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

Suppose I have a handler that computes some data from a request (e.g. the user ID) and that data is used by subsequent code in the application.

I can think of two methods for passing this data along:

**1. Mutate the `ctx.Items` collection**

This would look like this:

```ml
let authenticate : HttpHandler =
  fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) ->
    task {
      printfn "Authenticating... "

      let userID = Guid.NewGuid () // Dummy

      printfn "Authenticated as %A" userID

      ctx.Items.["userID"] <- userID

      return! next ctx
    }
```

Then to get the data, just do:

```ml
let showUser : HttpHandler =
  fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) ->
    task {
      let userID = ctx.Items.["userID"] :?> Guid

      return! text (sprintf "You are authenticated as %A. " userID) next ctx
    }
```

**2. Build a "wrapper" function (IoC)**

This would look like this:

```ml
let authenticated (innerHandler : Guid -> HttpHandler) : HttpHandler =
  fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) ->
    task {
      printfn "Authenticating... "

      let userID = Guid.NewGuid () // Dummy

      printfn "Authenticated as %A" userID

      return! (innerHandler userID) next ctx
    }
```

Getting the data is even easier and extra type-safe!

```ml
let showUser (userID : Guid) : HttpHandler =
  fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) ->
    task {
      return! text (sprintf "You are authenticated as %A. " userID) next ctx
    }
```

However you lose some composition with `>=>`.

**Questions**

- What approach did the Giraffe designers intend?
- What are the trade-offs with each approach?

Comment: The third option, naturally, is to avoid passing data in the handler chain. Do any preprocessing in the aspnetcore builder magic and pass ass params to your route function.

Comment: @Guran Happy to accept that as an answer if it is the preferred approach

Comment: It's one approach, but I really cannot tell if it is preferrable. Really good question anyway.

Comment: I use the second approach and it works well for me - the code is a lot cleaner IMO